# How to shift + click to select multiple checkboxes using checklist-model directive?

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

Is there any way to shift + click to select multiple checkboxes using this directive like we have in Gmail?

Example:

1. Click on 1st row's checkbox.
2. Holding down SHIFT key.
3. Click on 10th row's checkbox.

Result: the first 10th rows will be selected.

Comment: Can we have what you have already? Show some research you have done already so we can help and expand upon it

Comment: check if `event.shiftKey` is `true` and if any lesser or higher index element is already checked, after that you just have to push all in between elements into selected array!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it, the selectors will need to be changed to something more specific when it is used in something with more that just the check-boxes.

It works by scanning all the inputs and seeing if it is checked, if it is it toggles a boolean that will cause each element to toggle to checked until the this matches the clicked item then breaks out of the loop as it doesnt need to check any more.

```js
$("[type='checkbox']").click(function(evt) {
    if (evt.shiftKey){
      let item = $(this);
      let hitfirstChecked = false;
      $("#wrapper-check input").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
          hitfirstChecked = true;
        }
        if(hitfirstChecked){
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
        if(item.is($(this))){
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="wrapper-check">
<input type="checkbox" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" value="5">5
<input type="checkbox" value="6">6
<input type="checkbox" value="7">7
<input type="checkbox" value="8">8
</span>
```

Comment: this is right, but I am looking for solution related to checklist-model directive, like how to maintain previous selection(at parent scope maybe) as every element is new instance, etc

Comment: @AnujaJoshi your question does not ask that though it asks how to do shift select, there is only selection adapting needed to make this work for that

Comment: Note that this solution is incomplete: it only supports shift-clicking if the 2nd selection is BELOW the first.